# Conundrum due to space averaging electric field inside a charge distribution while calculating the macroscopic Electric field

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electric-fields, coulombs-law, dielectric

Given a charge distribution, we are generally interested in the macroscopic electric fields by which we mean the space averaged microscopic fields over a region around the point whose dimensions are well large in comparison to a molecule. Now when calculating the field, we know that the coulombs law holds true only above the scales of $10^{-16} m$. In practice, doing the space averaging for particles well outside this boundary is trivial, as it is simply the electric field at the centre of the sphere (supposing that the boundary is spherical). But let's suppose there exists a particle (or a bunch of particles) just outside the boundary, at a distance less than $10^{-16} m$ from the boundary, how would we take the fields due to these particles into account and do the volume averaging, since we are not able to calculate it using coulomb's law till regions that are $10^{-16} m$ away from these particles. Suppose we still force these particles to obey coulomb's law and force it into my space averaging, then wouldn't there be gross errors in the final theoretical result in comparison with reality? How would, in actuality, the forces due to particles present at distances less than $10^{-16} m$ look like, where coulomb's law does not hold?

Comment: You are always welcome to speculate about something in science that doesn't exist, it just won't lead to a useful insight. Of course, if you mean to say that one can't describe the inside of protons with Maxwell's equations, then you are correct. That requires quantum chormodynamics.

Comment: Can you give reference for the claims you make about 1) the Coulomb law holding only for scales greater than 1e-16 m and 2) average field is simply the field at the center of the sphere?

Comment: @JánLalinský , A) "observations have upheld the law on the scale from 10−16 m to 108 m." Copied from Wikipedia, B) DJ Griffiths actually gives this claim as a problem in the previous sections of his text, here the fields in question are explicitly the fields due to points outside the sphere.

Comment: After some time in physics, as Griffiths will also guide you through, you should stop using Coulomb's Law as the fundamental and start using Maxwell's equations. Then you will not be worried about the singularity of Coulomb's Law. This spatial averaging is covered in greater detail in JD Jackson, but even there, it is left incomplete, because it is merely a conceptual treatment and nobody really does it that way. Kittel does a better job, and we do use it, but Effective Medium Theory can be used to show that it is internally inconsistent. The proper way to solve this is not yet found.

Comment: > *"wouldn't there be gross errors in the final theoretical result"* Which theoretical result depends on field space averaging and charged particles being closer than 1e-16 m? Your question is hard to understand, what exactly are you trying to calculate? Effects of hypothetical non-Coulomb field at distances lower than 1e-16 m are unlikely to be detectable in macroscopic phenomena, whose description motivates introduction of macroscopic field via averaging of the microscopic field.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent The usually taught spatial averaging (a la what is in Jackson, or in Russakoff's article) seems to me to have the problem that it produces a function that still contains all the details, just in "less visible" way (since it looks like a reversible integral transform). Can you link to some approachable description of the problem with internal consistency?

Comment: @JánLalinský Look up the book titled "Effective Medium Theory". It is a rather simple problem: If the scheme in Kittel is exactly correct, then you should get the same result expanding starting from a background with $\epsilon_1$ to $\epsilon_2$, or the other way around. But the method somehow gives a different result, so it is not internally consistent in that way. But it still seems to be quite predictive.